# How can I combine these commands to achieve circular crop in ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

How can I combine these commands to achieve circular crop in ImageMagick?

So this command works:

```
convert -size 200x200 xc:none -fill samia.jpg -draw "circle 100,100 100,1" circle_thumb.png
```

The above will take a picture and make a circular crop out of it BUT the crop will be based on the upper left corner of the picture not the center of the picture.

This command also works for cropping:

```
convert *.jpg -resize 200x200^ -gravity Center -crop 200x200+0+0 +repage out.png
```

The above will make a square crop of an image based on the center of the image.

So what I want to do is to combine both commands.

My aim:

A command that takes a picture as input and makes a circular crop of it based on the center of the picture, not based on the upper left corner of the picture.

Anyone with IM skills who can show a dude how to resolve this?

Vesa

Ubuntu 15.10

Update:

I tried Mark Setchell's solution below but got the following error message:

```
axx@axx-VPCEA3S1E:~/Desktop/circular-crop$ magick samia.png \( +clone -threshold 101% -fill white -draw 'circle %[fx:int(w/2)],%[fx:int(h/2)] %[fx:int(w/2)],%[fx:80+int(h/2)]' \) -channel-fx '| gray=>alpha'   circle.png
magick: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
magick: no image to apply a property "%w" @ warning/property.c/GetMagickPropertyLetter/2561.
magick: unknown image property "%w" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3499.
magick: no image to apply a property "%h" @ warning/property.c/GetMagickPropertyLetter/2449.
magick: unknown image property "%h" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3499.
magick: no image to apply a property "%m" @ warning/property.c/GetMagickPropertyLetter/2480.
magick: unknown image property "%m" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3499.
axx@axx-VPCEA3S1E:~/Desktop/circular-crop$
```

Answer (score 16):

This question gets asked a lot.

Given an image larger than circle.

```
convert -size 300x300 plasma: input.png
```

[image: input.png]

We can draw a shape, convert values to alpha channel, and compose it over the input image.

```
convert input.png \
        -gravity Center \
        \( -size 200x200 \
           xc:Black \
           -fill White \
           -draw 'circle 100 100 100 1' \
           -alpha Copy \
        \) -compose CopyOpacity -composite \
        -trim output.png
```

[image: output]

Now if your planing to crop *many* resources, I would highly suggest creating a mask once. The reuse the mask as needed.

```
convert -size 200x200 xc:Black -fill White -draw 'circle 100 100 100 1' -alpha Copy mask.png

for f in $(ls *.jpg)
do
  convert $f -gravity Center mask.png -compose CopyOpacity -composite -trim ${f}_output.png
done
```

Comment: Hi emcconville. That is a cool solution. Only one thing, the output image is like I want it but surrounded by a large transparent field. Is it possible to have the image output autocropped into a neat square that just barely covers the edges of the circle if you see what I mean.

Comment: Simple. Just at `-trim` as the last operation. I'll updated the examples.

Comment: what is `Center mask.png` in this case should this be `Copy mask.png` instead?

Comment: What does `100 100 100 1` mean? I am thinking of cropping a circle of radius `r` and center `(x,y)`.

Comment: `x y w z` means: draw a circle centered at `x,y` and passing through `w,z`. So `100 100 100 1` is the circle at the center of the `200x200` square, and with radius 99. Why they don't just make it three numbers, `x,y,r`, I don't know...

Answer (score 7):

Not sure about *cropping circles*, but if you want to make all but a central circle transparent, you can do this...

**Start image**

[image]

Extract a circle with radius 80, using:

```
magick start.png \( +clone -threshold 101% -fill white -draw 'circle %[fx:int(w/2)],%[fx:int(h/2)] %[fx:int(w/2)],%[fx:80+int(h/2)]' \) -channel-fx '| gray=>alpha'   circle.png
```

[image]

Comment: Love the FX solution!

Comment: I'm interested in your solution, any idea why there was an error message?

Comment: You are running an old version of ImageMagick - older than v7.

Comment: Updated to ImageMagick 7.x. Tested again. New error message: magick samia.png \( +clone -threshold 101% -fill white -draw 'circle %[fx:int(w/2)],%[fx:int(h/2)] %[fx:int(w/2)],%[fx:80+int(h/2)]' \) -channel-fx '| gray=>alpha'   circle.png

magick: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
magick: no image to apply a property "%w" @ warning/property.c/GetMagickPropertyLetter/2561.
magick: unknown image property "%w" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3499...

Comment: It's really hard to read error messages in comments, can you click `edit` under your original question and put them in there please? Is your starting file a PNG or a JPEG? Did you leave spaces around the parentheses exactly as I showed?

Comment: Added error message in original question. File is a PNG. I copy pasted your command line input, only changed the name of the file but that should be ok.

Comment: Mmmm, please try a simple conversion from PNG to JPEG to make sure you have all the libraries installed and configured correctly... `magick samia.png samia.jpg`

Comment: It doesn't work to me: convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `circle' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4466

Comment: @Kred Please check your ImageMagick version - `identify -version`

Comment: @Mark Setchell 7.0.10-23

Comment: @Kred Questions are free and comments aren't an ideal place for code, so please ask a new question showing your images, your code and your error messages.  Click on the `share` button above this comment and copy a link to here and paste it into your new question to refer back here. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576578/image-magick-error-in-unix-non-conforming-drawing-primitive-definition-circle